# ¿Cómo optimizar un break para salir de multiples iteraciones?

Tags: php, optimización, buenas-prácticas

Tengo un pequeño dilema con este código.

Se trata de verificar un valor dentro del segundo bucle `for`. En cuanto ese valor se encuentre quiero salir de todo, retornando un dato.

### Opción A

Si lo escribo así, teniendo una variable `$mOption` que sea devuelta al final funciona bien, pero no está optimizado, porque el bucle padre sigue corriendo, puesto que el  `break` está dentro del bucle hijo:

```
function getOption ($arraySuperior,$mValue){
    /*Variable de respuesta seteada a NULL por defecto*/
    $mOption=NULL;
    foreach ($arraySuperior as $key=>$subArray){
        foreach ($subArray as $k=>$v){
            echo "$key\n";            
            if ($v==$mValue){
                /*
                    Sólo en este caso la variable cambiará de valor
                    siendo éste el de la clave siguiente a donde se encuentre a $mValue
                */
                echo "Encontrado!\n";
                $mOption=$subArray[$k+1];
                /* Encontrado el valor, no seguimos iterando sobre el array*/
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $mOption;
}
```

**Prueba:**

```
$mOption=getOption($arraySuperior,"site_name");
var_dump($mOption);
```

**Salida:**

```
0
0
Encontrado!
1
1
1
2
2
2
string(8) "FullAuth"
```

Como se puede ver, el dato fue encontrado en el índice `0`, pero sigue recorriendo el arreglo, dado que el `break` está dentro del `for` hijo. Por lo tanto, el código no está optimizado. Debería salir y no seguir imprimiendo los índices 1,2.

### Opción B

Si escribo la función así, parece que está optimizado:

```
function getOption ($arraySuperior,$mValue){
    /*Variable de respuesta seteada a NULL por defecto*/
    //$mOption=NULL;
    foreach ($arraySuperior as $key=>$subArray){
        foreach ($subArray as $k=>$v){
            echo "$key\n";            
            if ($v==$mValue){
                /*
                    Sólo en este caso la variable cambiará de valor
                    siendo éste el de la clave siguiente a donde se encuentre a $mValue
                */
                echo "Encontrado!\n";
                return $subArray[$k+1];

            }
        }
    }
    //return $mOption;
}
```

**Prueba:**

Es exactamente la misma de antes:

```
$mOption=getOption($arraySuperior,"site_name");
var_dump($mOption);
```

**Salida:**

```
0
0
Encontrado!
string(8) "FullAuth"
```

Lo que me incomoda de esta segunda opción (que parece estar optimizada), es que **no hay un control sobre lo que se retorna en la función** Dicho de otro modo, sólo se retorna un valor cuando se encuentra algo, desde esta fila: `return $subArray[$k+1];`. Pero en caso de no encontrar nada, ningún `return` ocurre.

Ahora si pruebo con un valor que no exista, ocurre esto:

```
$mOption=getOption($arraySuperior,"fake");
var_dump($mOption);
```

**Salida:**

```
0
0
0
1
1
1
2
2
2
NULL
```

Se puede ver que al final el resultado es `NULL`. Sé que PHP es algo permisivo y asume (según mi parecer), que si encuentra nada, el valor de la variable será `NULL`. Pero no quiero acogerme a esa permisividad de PHP y quiero saber alguna forma de optimizar el código, de forma que pueda tener un control de lo que se retorne, como ocurre en la opción **A**, pero sin que tenga que seguir leyendo el array si se encuentra el dato.

Comment: Pero es correcto que returne null, ya que no encontro nada... que quisieras que retorne?

Comment: @gbianchi la cuestión es que no hay un control del rotorno en el caso **B**. En otros lenguajes ese código sería erróneo, ¿no? Esa es mi duda.

Comment: Ese codigo seria erroneo en algunos lenguajes porque te diria que falta un return. en el caso B, seria el return que esta comentado... pero tranquilamente ese ultimo return puede devolver null...

Comment: ¡Ah! claro. Dices que sería cuestión de poner un `return NULL` al final del bucle padre. Claro, tienes razón.

Comment: Excato. .Net por ejemplo te daria un error de que no todas las rutas devuelven un valor, porque el return debe ser explicito, aunque sea de un null.

Comment: @gbianchi claro, no sé como no se me ocurrió. Propongo que lo pongas como respuesta si te parece.

Comment: Para la opción **A** una vez que encuentra lo que quieres, para salir del bucle hijo pones un `break`, pero después sigue iterando el padre. Has probado a poner un `break` justo debajo de la llave de cierre del foreach hijo? Creo que así saldrá del bucle padre, y no mostrara los indices 1 y 2

Comment: @MarioGuiber creo que es más simple usar la opción `B`, implementando lo que dice gbianchi, o sea, poner  un `return NULL;` para controlar el retorno en caso de que no se encuentre nada. PHP lo asume por defecto, pero yo me digo que tengo que ser estricto al escribir el código y no dejar que PHP tome esas decisiones por mi (en otros lenguajes daría error si se omite el return en ese caso).

Comment: @A.Cedano totalmente de acuerdo, buena forma la que dice gbianchi. También de acuerdo con lo de no dejar que PHP tome esas decisiones. Esperaremos la respuesta de gbianchi, ya que es la mas simple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para tratar de ser un poco mas estricto en nuestra forma de programar, es necesario ser ordenados y aunque el lenguaje que usamos permita hacer algunas cosas implicitas, explicitarlas para que otros desarrolladores entiendan de que estamos hablando.

Como primera medida, aunque php haga un retorno automatico de una variable, en muchos lenguajes es importante explicitar cuando se hace un `return` de una función y que es lo que se va a devolver.

Para este caso, la opcion B es correcta, pero dejando el codigo sin comentar el return al final de la función. Mas alla que PHP lo permita, en otro lenguajes los compiladores protestarian que hay rutas de codigo (en este caso, cuando no encuentra nada) que no devuelven nada (o no se sabe que se quiere devolver). Entonces el código deberia quedar asi:

```
function getOption ($arraySuperior,$mValue){
    /*Variable de respuesta seteada a NULL por defecto*/
    //$mOption=NULL;
    foreach ($arraySuperior as $key=>$subArray){
        foreach ($subArray as $k=>$v){
            echo "$key\n";            
            if ($v==$mValue){
                /*
                    Sólo en este caso la variable cambiará de valor
                    siendo éste el de la clave siguiente a donde se encuentre a $mValue
                */
                echo "Encontrado!\n";
                return $subArray[$k+1];

            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Existiria otra forma de programar esto, para aquellos que son de la escuela donde solo se puede tener un return por función.

Para ello, la funcion A deberia tener una comprobación mas:

```
function getOption ($arraySuperior,$mValue){
    /*Variable de respuesta seteada a NULL por defecto*/
    $mOption=NULL;
    foreach ($arraySuperior as $key=>$subArray){
        foreach ($subArray as $k=>$v){
            echo "$key\n";            
            if ($v==$mValue){
                /*
                    Sólo en este caso la variable cambiará de valor
                    siendo éste el de la clave siguiente a donde se encuentre a $mValue
                */
                echo "Encontrado!\n";
                $mOption=$subArray[$k+1];
                /* Encontrado el valor, no seguimos iterando sobre el array*/
                break;
            }
            if ($mOption != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $mOption;
}
```

Donde si en la ultima vuelta ya encontro un item, salga tambien del `for` exterior.

Igual, [segun el manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.break.php), break es una funcion rara que permite recibir un parametro que en este caso es la cantidad de estructuras de iteración que se deben cortar.

Por lo tanto, uno podria escribir A de la siguiente forma:

```
function getOption ($arraySuperior,$mValue){
    /*Variable de respuesta seteada a NULL por defecto*/
    $mOption=NULL;
    foreach ($arraySuperior as $key=>$subArray){
        foreach ($subArray as $k=>$v){
            echo "$key\n";            
            if ($v==$mValue){
                /*
                    Sólo en este caso la variable cambiará de valor
                    siendo éste el de la clave siguiente a donde se encuentre a $mValue
                */
                echo "Encontrado!\n";
                $mOption=$subArray[$k+1];
                /* Encontrado el valor, no seguimos iterando sobre el array*/
                break 2;
            }
        }
    }
    return $mOption;
}
```

y ese `break 2;` saldria de los dos for, dejando un solo return y un solo corte en las estructuras.

Comment: No sabía lo del `break 2;`  (aunque no soy partidario de recurrir a esas *cosas raras*)... Otra cosa en la que había pensado era en un `while`, pero no me molesta que haya dos `return`, a mi juicio es totalmente válido. Así que me quedo con la opción **B**, con un `return NULL;`, porque creo que es lo más simple. Gracias por todo.

Comment: un while con banderas es totalmente valido tambien.

Comment: Buena respuesta. Solo un detalle: si utilizamos php7 y utilizamos la opcion de indicar en la funcion el tipo de retorno, si hay una parte que no tiene indicado el return correspondiente nos dara error, por lo que se hace necesario que haya una salida siempre con ese tipo. (solo para que lo tengais en cuenta en la respuesta, @gbianchi

Comment: @Jakala en ese caso sólo habría que cambiar el `return NULL;` por un `return '';`, ¿cierto?